# Escaping someway the Todo keyword in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm developing an example of web application (in Java) which is used to manage **Todo** tasks. Thus I have an entity called Todo and obviously in many comments I use the **Todo** word referring to my Todo entity (not to a TODO item regarding the code), e.g.

```
/**
 * Todo entity model.
 */
@Entity
public class Todo {
```

in result I'm getting this warning from IntelliJ IDEA

```
Warning:(*, 2) Complete the task associated to this TODO comment.
```

I've tried to use `{@code Todo}` and `{@literal Todo}`, but the warning does not disappear. How can I escape the Todo keyword in order to get rid of warnings from IDEA?

Comment: Use more meaningful comments? It's fairly obvious it's a `Todo`entity. Why not describe it better? FE, "An entity that does such and such."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the todo setting for IDEA ...

File -> Settings -> Editor -> TODO - adjust the `\btodo\b.*` entry: either remove it or perhaps change to uppercase and enable the case-sensitive option.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to change the regex use to match TODOs in Intellij, to prevent matching those cases where the Todo is between curly braces.
Considering the example below:

```
/**
 * {@code org.reminder.Todo}
 * Todo this is the only matching TODO task
 * NotaTODO in this line
 *
 */
```

The following regex for TODOs (in menu File -> Settings -> Editor -> TODO), will match the desired TODOs in any case:

```
\btodo(\b[^}]).*
```

Further description about the regex for Intellij IDEA is available at [Intellij IDEA- Regular Expression Syntax Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html).